# How to add a file library and be able to edit it

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I want to use a specific file in `Webstorm IDE` for help with the autocomplete on other files, Im using the `module pattern` so one file has the main methods used for the others modules. So in Webstorm I added this file as a library as is explained here `http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html` .

The problem is that now that is a library I CANT edit it any more or add new code to this file. So I have to remove it from the Webstorm scope to be able to edit it. And then add it again in the scope(library) when Im working in the other files and has the ability to use the autocomplete.

So how can I add this file as a library AND tell webstorm that he should let me add and edit current content for this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library files write protection was implemented by design to prevent users from making accidental modifications to them. Recommended workflow is to open library files as separate project for editing, or include them not as "library" but as a separate content root. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1065 requires making the current behavior optional. You are welcome to vote for it

Comment: Omg, this is such a bad idea, they should let us decide what we want, I dont think push JB Team idea in our process is a good approach for us. Well Anyway sad until they change it.Do you know if exist a work around for this? Thanks for the support. :D

Comment: see above: 'Recommended workflow is to open library files as separate project for editing, or include them not as "library" but as a separate content root'

Comment: SO users, this two year old issue linked above could really use a few upvotes to get it prioritised.